# How to get the scan.nextLine() without skipping it

Tags: java, try-catch

```
public void readDrinks(File file) throws DrinkReaderException{
            try {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
                scan.useDelimiter("::");
                String name,category;
                int price;
                boolean premium;
                while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    name = "";category = ""; price = -1;
                    if(scan.hasNext())
                        name = scan.next();
                    if(scan.hasNext())
                        category = scan.next();
                    if(scan.hasNextInt())
                        price = scan.nextInt();
                    if(scan.hasNextBoolean())
                        premium = scan.nextBoolean();
                    else
                        premium = false;
                    System.out.println(name + category + price + premium);
                    if(name.isEmpty() || category.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.printf("--Skip the item: %s\n");
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(price == -1 ) {
                        System.out.printf("--Incorrect price skip: %s\n");
                        continue;
                    }
                    readerList.add(new Drink(name,category,price,premium));
                }
                scan.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                readFileUI();
            }
    }
```

I'm not sure on how to make it so that if the object lack name or category it will print itself like  "--Skip the item: Iced Coffe::30"
because if I were to make a = scan.nextLine() and then put a as %s in name.isEmpty || category.isEmpty  it will skip the current line to the next line which will make scan.next() scan.nextInt() scan.nextBoolean()   reading the next Line

this is the file of "list of item" I need to do

```
Name::Category::0::true
Espresso::Hot Coffee::35::false
Chocolate Milk Shake::Cool Drink::60::true 
Hot Plain Milk::Hot Milk::false 
Honey Lemon Iced Tea::Ice Tea::40::false
Double Chocolate Milk Shake::Iced Milk::50::true
Hot Chinese Tea::Hot Tea::30:: false
Iced Caramel Milk::Iced Milk::40
Iced Mocha::Iced Coffee::40::false
Iced Coffee::30
Hot Americano::Hot Coffee::40::false
```

and this is the result I was hoping to make
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjKWd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would basically keep your same structure, but instead of using one `Scanner` I would use two of them: one to read each file's line and a second one (yours) to fetch the data from each line.

```
public void readDrinks(File file) throws DrinkReaderException {
        try {
            Scanner scanLines = new Scanner(file);
            String line, name, category;
            int price;
            boolean premium;

            while (scanLines.hasNextLine()) {
                //EDIT: added a trim to get rid of eventual spaces at the end and properly read a boolean
                line = scanLines.nextLine().trim();

                Scanner scanParams = new Scanner(line);
                scanParams.useDelimiter("::");

                name = "";
                category = "";
                price = -1;

                if (scanParams.hasNext())
                    name = scanParams.next();
                if (scanParams.hasNext())
                    category = scanParams.next();
                if (scanParams.hasNextInt())
                    price = scanParams.nextInt();
                if (scanParams.hasNextBoolean())
                    premium = scanParams.nextBoolean();
                else
                    premium = false;
                System.out.println(name + " - " + category + " - " + price + " - " + premium);
                if (name.isEmpty() || category.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.printf("--Skip the item: %s%n", line);
                    continue;
                }
                if (price == -1) {
                    System.out.printf("--Incorrect price skip: %s%n", line);
                    continue;
                }
                readerList.add(new Drink(name, category, price, premium));
            }
            scanLines.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            readFileUI();
        }
    }
```

##### Output

[image]

Comment: nextBoolean kinda not scanning the true/false. I'm guessing it's because Delimiter only affects next();  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Nooboolean I've copied your exact file and noticed that for some lines it managed to return true where there is true and for some others doesn't. Turned out that in your file, rows 3 and 4 have a space after their respective true and false. If you get rid of them by correcting the file or by simply trimming the read line you should be fine. My output complies to what you expected now.

Comment: I got this file by professor. Alright Thanks! I will try that.